# Is there a way to import an older version of tensor flow to use in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I keep getting this error when running my python 3.8 code:
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'SessionRunHook'

I previously read that this is because the tensorflow version is not correct. How do I use a different version of tensorflow?

I have tried:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
print(tf.__version__)
```

but it still shows that I am using tensorflow version 2.5.0.

I have also tried

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import absolute_import

import argparse
import os
import pandas as pd

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '0'
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
print(tf.__version__)
import numpy as np

from dltk.networks.regression_classification.resnet import resnet_3d
from dltk.io.abstract_reader import Reader
```

The attribute error seems to appear at the last line when I try to import dltk.io.abstract_reader.

Comment: yes, it shows ver 2.5 correctly, u need to access everything v1 from name space `tf.compat.v1.*`

Comment: tf 2 has tf 1 inside at `tf.compat.v1`

Comment: Using tensorflow.compat.va did not solve the error.

Comment: anyway, try to convert your code to tf 2. TensorFlow 1 will be deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall the package and install an older version. The grammar is like `pip install tensorflow==<version>`.
If you would like to keep the two versions at the same time, I'm afraid you should use anaconda.

Comment: Any idea what these errors mean? ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15

Comment: I also got the same error, although tensorflow 1.15 IS in pypi. Try download the whl files from [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.15.0/#files) and install the package.

Comment: the older version of tensorflow required python 3.7, so i created a new condo env with python 3.7 and was able to download the required version of tensorflow. thanks for your help!!!